# Fermipy LAT/3ML undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to do some astronomical analysis using 3ML (a data analysis tool) and the fermipy module. My work is very specific so I do not expect a very specific answer, just any sort of guidance as to what is going on. I'm working with Ubuntu and Python. 3ML is an activated virtual environment, which I am working inside.

Towards the end of the traceback, you'll see the `healpy_sph_transform_lib.so` file mentioned. After attempting to import, `from . import _healpy_sph_transform_lib as sphtlib`, the `.so` file reaches this unknown symbol "`GOMP_parallel`". I cannot open the `.so` file so I cannot inspect it any further.

I know GOMP is a software, but it feels very unrelated to what I'm doing, although I have no experience with GOMP. Would installing it do me any good? I'm looking for guidance on the "missing symbol" aspect of the error. I don't even know how to attack that issue at all. Any advice as to "what to look for" would be helpful.

I know my question is not too much information, but I created a stack account solely to resolve this issue. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.Thank You.

```
>>> LAT=FermipyLike("LAT",config)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/threeML/plugins/FermipyLike.py", line 209, in __new__
    _expensive_imports_hook()
  File "/home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/threeML/plugins/FermipyLike.py", line 190, in _expensive_imports_hook
    from fermipy.gtanalysis import GTAnalysis
  File "/home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fermipy/gtanalysis.py", line 16, in <module>
    import fermipy.defaults as defaults
  File "/home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fermipy/defaults.py", line 8, in <module>
    import fermipy.skymap
  File "/home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fermipy/skymap.py", line 5, in <module>
    import healpy as hp
  File "/home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/healpy/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .sphtfunc import (anafast, map2alm,
  File "/home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/healpy/sphtfunc.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import _healpy_sph_transform_lib as sphtlib
ImportError: /home/max/anaconda2/3ML_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/healpy/_healpy_sph_transform_lib.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading and installing xgboost solved the problem for me.